# How to return the string formed by alternating the case of the characters?

Tags: java

The method is supposed to return the string formed by alternating the case of the characters in a specified string. The first character in the returned string is in lowercase, the second character is in uppercase, the third character is in lowercase, the fourth character is in uppercase, and so on.
Example: tOrOnTo.

```
public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I am expecting this to work, however it keeps failing the JUnit test.

Comment: Your function doesn't **return** the string with the alternating case characters, it returns the input string unchanged. (`Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))` doesn't change `s` in any way, it just gives you the capped character as a return value.) It **outputs** the string with the alternating case characters. You need to build a new string within the method and then return that new string.

Comment: Can you also post in your test code? If you are using the return value of the function for performing some assertion, then it would fail since `String s` is unchanged.

Comment: You could also compute `s.length()` and store its value in a variable before initializing the for-loop.

Comment: Do you want to print the string, or return it? It is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDK, why all other solutions have missed out one of the requisite (First character has to be in lower-case, `0%2 == 0`). Your test code would still be failing.

The correct solution would be,

```
 public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        result.append(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
      } else {
        result.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
 }
```

---

PS: Swap the method calls, `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` on other answers to obtain right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the processed `String`, you are just printing it out on the StdOut so the input `String` is not altered and your jUnit fails.

Here using a `StringBuilder`, append the processed characters and finally return the `String` by calling the `toString()` method on the `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    IntStream.range(0, s.length()).forEach(idx ->{
        if (idx % 2 == 0) {
            temp.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(idx)));
        }else {
            temp.append(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(idx)));
        }
    });
    return temp.toString();
}
```

Another way using `Collectors#joining` and `IntStream` where you iterate over the indexes of the input `String` apply the logic and collect it using `Collectors#joining` :

```
public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
           .mapToObj(idx -> String.valueOf(idx % 2 == 0 
                           ? Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(idx)) 
                           : Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(idx))))
           .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with arrays.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = alternatingCaps("toronto");
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
        char [] array = new char[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                array[i]=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
            } else {
                array[i]=Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(array); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Java, so you cannot modify it. All methods that modify a string, internally create a new string and return it.

I think the best solution is to use `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String alternatingCaps(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        buf.append(i % 2 == 0 ? Character.toLowerCase(ch) : Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you were not actually changing the value you were returning, and only were printing the modified values.

I took an alternative approach to this to demonstrate another way to change every other value without using the modulo:

```
public static String alternatingCaps(String s) {
    boolean toggle = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (toggle = !toggle) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }
        else {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This uses the `StringBuilder` to build the return `String` and uses `String.toCharArray()` with an enhanced `for` loop to iterate through all the characters instead of an index.

We are able to use the enhanced `for` loop here *because* we changed how we determine if the index is odd or even.  Instead of using the modulo we use `boolean` value that toggles between `true` and `false` with each pass through which effectively does the same thing.

Note that this method is overall inferior to the modulo approach because the modulo can be easily modified if you want every third value etc... and is easier to read than this approach.  This example is mainly for learning other ways to approach problems.

I also avoided the ternary operator so it is easier to see how the `boolean` toggling works, though it can be simplified further by using it.